# How to use a cocoapod libraly (ConvenientImagePicker) to NativeModule in react native?

Tags: react-native, imagepicker

I'm trying to find a library to pick image on device. beautiful like ConvenientImagePicker (https://cocoapods.org/pods/ConvenientImagePicker) but I can't find it in npm library.
I want my react native app to have an imagepicker component like this, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) on how to create "native modules" to expose native code to JavaScript. Note that since this is an iOS only library, you'll have to find an equivalent Android library.

Comment: I have been able to understand the connection between Object-C and Reactive by this guide. But I don't understand native language. I don't know how to install the cocopod library up to the connection to the react native. I can't find a dedicated manual or video tutorial.

Comment: You simply have to add the library to your `Podfile` as described in the [documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html).